# Unable to extend Facebook access token to 60 days

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am having trouble to extend the expiration time of Facebook access token to 60 days.
I was reading several articles on Facebook developer page:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Specifically, I am using Facebook C# SDK, and when I ask for authentication,
I am doing FacebookClient.GetLoginUrl(), and work on the call by to get the access token.

Right after that, I try to use FacebookClient.GetAsync("oauth/access_token") to extend the expiration time by using the following URL pattern

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

However, I don't see the expiration time of the access_token being extended.
I did set my app to use deprecated offline_access...
Anyone have experience with Facebook C# SDK and could give me some thoughts on this?

Did I misunderstand the meaning of "extend expiration time" means in Facebook doc?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a bug in Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241373692605971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call you're making will return an access token, quite possibly not the same one you passed in. In other words, *your existing token won't necessarily be extended*, you may get a new one if required.

Comment: Which means I should extend the token only when it is about to expire, right? But in that case, is the token being extends for 60 days in one call? Or I need to extend the expiration time day by day? I think it is not very clear in the Facebook doc. At least I thought making the call will always extend the token to be 60 days lifetime.

Comment: @KaneHo You can extend it at most once a day, and you can extend it to 60 days in one call. In other words, if you get a token for my user that expires in 60 days and I log back in in two days, you can extend access to 60 days again at that time. You don't need to wait until it expires.

Comment: That's what I feel confused about. Can you point me to sample on how to do that 60 days call?

Comment: @KaneHo, yep user need to re-login before his `access_token` may be extended (this wasn't stated specifically in docs for offline access deprecation). Actually [Re-Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/) will work too ;)

Comment: It turns out that the issue I was hitting is because of this bug: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241373692605971) Unauthorize and authorize the app again can solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enhanced oauth dialog enabled and your redirect_uri is pointing to your website.